# mvc readonly datetime updates to 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm creating an MVC 5.2 and cannot seem to get the DateTime field to be readonly and not get updated after an Edit.  I insert a row and the date is set to the current datetime.  Then when I edit the row in the MVC view the datetime becomes 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.  What do I need to do to get the datetime to display but not update when I edit the row?

```
    [Table("Employee")]
public partial class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int TestID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
[TestID]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[LastUpdated] DATETIME2 (7) DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestID] ASC));
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't plan on changing the value in the database, if you want the value to persist across a POST request you need to bind it to an input:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LastUpdated)
```

Hopefully, you're not using your EF objects in your views, but even then, you can control what gets updated:

```
var emp = context.Employess.SingleOrDefault(e => e.TestID == model.TestID);
if(emp != null)
{
    emp.Name = model.Name;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Assuming, of course, that `context` is an instance of your EF DbContext and `model` is the name of the parameter:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Employee model)
{
    /* ... */
}
```